# Cabal library version probelm (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I hope this is not OT but it's certainly no StackOverflow question so I try here.
I've got a problem with my cabal install on a Windows 7 (64bit) machine.

If I try do run a yesod devel it tells me to rerun the configure because I switched the cabal library (1.10.1.0 instead of 1.10.2.0) and no small wonder - if I run cabal --version I get:

```
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

but if I do the same in the cabal/bin folder I will get the right version ot the library. So there must be some strange path problems but I just cannot find it and I tried to cabal-install, etc. (even renaming the cabal.exe because of the cannot change running process problem).

I'm lost - can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got your question answered by now.

For future readers. One solution is to add the cabal/bin folder to your path.

Another is to move the exe file to `C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin.` as recommend at `http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install#Windows`.